# Json datetime contains T where Time starts

Tags: c#, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

why my Json DateTime value has **T** before time.

1. Is it because the datatype is dateTime ?
2. Can i remove the T without changing the data type

```
 {
   "code": "Code",
   "date": "2018-05-02T20:02:24" //T
 },
```

**Code inside my web API**

```
public IEnumerable<Result> MethodName()
{
   var result = (from x in Context.Tabl1
                 select new Result
                 {
                   Code = x.Code,
                   Date = x.Date,// I dont want to apply ToString(format)
                 }).ToArray();
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
 {
    "code": "Code",
    "date": "2018-05-02 20:02:24" //Without T
  },
```

Comment: It's a *standard* (ISO 8601) datetime representation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: That's one of the permissible ISO 8601 formats, specifically the one you get with `.ToString("s")`. Since JSON has no native date/time type, there's quite a bit of variation in how they're formatted.

Comment: is converting to string with format is only option

Comment: "is converting to string with format is only option"??? Only strings can have formats. For a date (or date/time) to be formatted it must be a string.

Comment: i plan to convert to string to avoid the T. But now stay with the format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why my Json DateTime value has T before time.

Because that's what ISO-8601 says to do. There are various options for date/time values in ISO-8601, but all of them use a "T" to separate the date part from the time part. ISO-8601 is probably the most commonly-used format for machine-readable date and time representations as text.

The machine-readable part is important here. JSON is a machine-readable format that's also intended to be reasonable human-readable - like XML. It's not intended to be a format for non-developers to consume directly. Instead, a presentation layer (UI, report generator, whatever it is) is intended to format the underlying data ("a date and time") in the most appropriate representation for the user. That may use am/pm designators, month names, culture-specific formats etc - all of which are good for *human* consumption, but make *machine* consumption harder.

I strongly urge you *not* to move away from ISO-8601 here. That's the most appropriate representation for JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I would stay with ISO-8601